# Differences between Go and Cython

Tags: python, go, cython

Today a great friend of mine asked me what are the main differences between the newest Go language and [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), which is a set of C-extensions for Python. I don't have much knowledge on Python, can anyone tell me why Go is better/worse than Cython?

Comment: What are your criteria for determining better or worse? These are two entirely different programming languages; there are lots of differences, so it depends on what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I only want to know why someone should use Go instead of using cython, e.g., what can be done in Go that you can't easily be achieve with Cython? What languages have better performance? Better security? Better user-friendliness? Better debuggers? Or is it all the same thing only slight differing from syntax?

Comment: Lack of any sane thread support in Cython has killed my love for this language. 'cython nogil'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cython isn't really a language in the conventional sense. It is a preprocessor for building Python extensions that takes Python-like syntax (actually they strive for full Python compatibility) and produces C code (using the Python C API). Doing this they are able to include some special case optimisations, but the real benefits come when you add Cython specific static type information which is incorporated into the C code, bypassing the Python runtime for those operations and resulting in a high speed up.

Go is a compiled programming language. The first thing that can be done in Go is producing an executable that doesn't include the Python runtime/start a Python interpreter - this is impossible in Cython. (May not be technically impossible - but there is really no point to use Cython if you are not working with Python). Since Cython just produces C most of your questions in the comment don't really apply - you can use any C debugger (although the fact that's a Python extension makes things a bit more complicated).

Comment: About Cython: I disagree. You need to keep the mindset that you are working in C, NOT Python. Writing a stub loader isn't that hard as Python is open source.

Answer (score 5):

gevent is a concurrent library that uses Cython at its core. It seems to be pretty fast: http://nichol.as/asynchronous-servers-in-python

Comment: People seem to think that python (Cython) scales well, I used to be one of them until I learned the internals. look-up Global Interpreter Lock or GIL and see what I am talking about. In short, no true threading support.

Comment: I know what the GIL is. Hence suggesting gevent, which gets round the GIL using greenthreads. It's not as good as having native lightweight threads (like haskell, erlang or go) but it works well enough for IO bound apps and makes for a pleasant programming experience.

Comment: No concurrent multi-CPU support with greenthreads though?

Comment: no you're still looking at multiple process to make the most of extra CPUs unfortunately

Comment: in fact, cython supports `with nogil: ...` and parallel support using openmp -- in fact it works quite well for local optimizations. Gevent also works well if you have blocking code blocking (ie -- for channels). But its correct to note that lack of support in vanilla python makes these things more difficult. One possibility: use celery -- then you can distribute over multiple computers as well as multiple cores.

Answer (score 4):

Differences? Pretty much everything!

- Concurrency and channels.
- Interfaces.
- Static typechecking.
- ...

Comment: Ugh cython has all of these plus exploits 2 considerably more mature and powerful languages.

Comment: Last time I checked, Cython did not support threads well.

Answer (score 2):

What about support. You are relying on a single compiler, provided by Google. What if Go folds or goes commercial?

With Cython you could always go back to Python (or port the C code) if the Cython project folded.

*UPDATE: I must say that I am now upset with Cython.* ***The lack of thread support*** is a major blow. Cython is thread-safe BUT at a serious cost. The global interpreter lock is held the whole time a function executes. Thereby disabling concurrent execution over an entire codebase!

Cython's C-like features are poorly documented and confusing to novices. I admit.

*Cython's purpose is to support the Sage mathematics software; Go's is to support Google's ambitious plans for cutting-edge expensive $$ hardware.*

In short, I no longer like either one of these languages. Going back to C++ (again). *My favorite is **Cython**.*

Comment: This is wrong. It don't know if this was correct in 2010, but you do not have to hold the gil. You can release the gil anytime you don't need to make a python call using the with nogil syntex.

Comment: "single compiler, provided by Google" wrong on both counts. There is `gc` and there is [`gccgo`](https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo) (plus more I think, but those are the big ones). Go is fully open sourced with many non-Google contributors; Google could fold or abandon Go tomorrow and Go would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

GO introduces goroutines and channels. See language [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_lang_faq.html#goroutines)

Answer (score 1):

My main reason for trying out go is the supposed ease of introducing concurrency into programs.  I think that will be the 'next big thing', as processor speeds will tail off, and increasingly multiple cores are available.  If you want to make use of multicore processors, you need to write your program so that it can run things concurrently.

I earlier looked at Erlang, but despite being used to Prolog I find it a bit strange still; it is so different from your 'average' programming language (of the C or Pascal family).  But its concurrency features are easy to use, once you get the hang of it.  With very little effort I was able to write a parallel parser, which does not use a stack, but spawns a new 'thread/process' every time there were multiple options.

So far go looks quite alright, despite some slight inconsistencies.  And it's also fast, which is a bonus.

So unless Cython also makes concurrency easy, I'd favour go...

Comment: +1 for *easy to use*. Concurrency in various forms has been the "next big thing" for at least 30 years; but to "introduce concurrency" one must rethink, not easy.

Comment: Cython does not support concurrency **at all** (the GIL is held much of the time). Yeah, you could use multiple *processes* but that is an OS level concurrency, which is slow under Windows.