# Writing a Python extension in Go (Golang)

Tags: python, c, go, cython

I currently use Cython to link C and Python, and get speedup in slow bits of python code. However, I'd like to use goroutines to implement a really slow (and very parallelizable) bit of code, but it must be callable from python. (I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743526/differences-between-go-and-cython))

I'm (sort of) happy to go via C (or Cython) to set up data structures etc if necessary, but avoiding this extra layer would be good from a bug fix/avoidance point of view.

What is the simplest way to do this without having to reinvent any wheels?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Update 2015**: possible as of Go 1.5 https://blog.filippo.io/building-python-modules-with-go-1-5/

> with Go 1.5 you can build .so objects and import them as Python modules, running Go code (instead of C) directly from Python.

See also https://github.com/go-python/gopy

> gopy generates a CPython extension module from a go package.

Comment: The github.com/go-python/gopy project makes this absurdly easy, creating all the necessary plumbing for you that the blog post mentions.

Comment: gopy is currently not compatible with Go>=1.6, so that was short lived.

Comment: gopy was updated to support newer versions of Go. It is using the the "c-shared" build option and the pybindgen project

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. Go can run C code (and that C code can then call back into Go), but the [`main` function has to be in Go](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/nVw-Zgjt9Y8/PcegzOFp_pcJ), so the Go runtime can set things up.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to call go in a separate process trough xmlrpc then?

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much puts the idea to bed. The only way to do this, then, would be using something like `python_part_1 | go_program | python_part_2` using pipes (or intermediate files, or XMLRPC) to pass data?

Comment: You can use sockets to do RPC.

Comment: It is fairly easy to embed Python into a C program.  I wonder if you could then embed that C program into a Go program... The Python and Go interactions would have to go via the C layer.

Comment: For communicating between Go and Python processes, you could Go run the Python program in a different process and use stdin, stdout to communicate between the processes (package os/exec). JSON would be better than XMLRPC for this because currently XML is a little harder to work with in Go than JSON is.

Comment: If you're using the stdin/out/err pipe to communicate it's better to not use any text-based format. Go for msgpack or something lighter, or even just serialize your structs over the pipe. Python has pack/unpack and Go has encoding/binary for this.

Comment: This is now possible with Go 1.5 - see https://github.com/jbuberel/buildmodeshared for working examples.

Answer (score 4):

I've written an extension to setuptools which allows you to write cpython extensions that interface with go: https://github.com/asottile/setuptools-golang

There's a couple example extensions here:

- https://github.com/asottile/setuptools-golang-examples
- https://github.com/asottile/dockerfile

The neat thing is these can be installed just like any other `pip` package and support both cpython and pypy.

[PEP 513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) manylinux1 wheels can also be built to provide pre-built wheels via the `setuptools-golang-build-manylinux-wheels` tool.

The approach is nearly identical to the one in @ColonelPanic's answer but uses some additional tricks to enable python2 + python3 compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [go-python](https://github.com/sbinet/go-python) package precisely to help you write Python extensions in Go:

> this package provides an executable "go-python" which just loads
>   "python" and then call python.Py_Main(os.Args). the rational being
>   that under such an executable, go based extensions for C-Python would
>   be easier to implement (as this usually means calling into go from C
>   through some rather convoluted functions hops)

Comment: From what I read, `go-python` helps you invoke Python from Go, not the other way around.

Comment: This is what I had seen, and discarded, precisely because it was the other way around as @zneak put it.

Comment: I added a quote directly from the go-python readme that explains how to use it to build python extensions.