# Calling Python function from Go and getting the function return value

Tags: python, go

I am writing a [Go](http://golang.org/) program.  From this Go program, I would like to call a Python function defined in another file and receive the function's return value so I can use it in subsequent processing in my Go program.  I am having trouble getting any returned data back in my Go program though.  Below is a minimum example of what I thought would work, but apparently doesn't:

**gofile.go**

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import "fmt"

func main() {
     fmt.Println("here we go...")
     program := "python"
     arg0 := "-c"
     arg1 := fmt.Sprintf("'import pythonfile; print pythonfile.cat_strings(\"%s\", \"%s\")'", "foo", "bar")
     cmd := exec.Command(program, arg0, arg1)
     fmt.Println("command args:", cmd.Args)
     out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
     if err != nil {
         fmt.Println("Concatenation failed with error:", err.Error())
     return
     }
     fmt.Println("concatentation length: ", len(out))
     fmt.Println("concatenation: ", string(out))
     fmt.Println("...done")
}
```

**pythonfile.py**

```
def cat_strings(a, b):
    return a + b
```

If I call `go run gofile` I get the following output:

```
here we go...
command args: [python -c 'import pythonfile; print pythonfile.cat_strings("foo", "bar")']
concatentation length:  0
concatenation:  
...done
```

A few notes:

- I'm using the `-c` flag in the Python invocation so I can call the function `cat_strings` directly.  Assume `cat_strings` is part of a Python file full of utility functions that are used by other Python programs, hence why I don't have any `if __name__ == __main__` business.
- I don't want to modify the Python file to `print a + b` (instead of `return a + b`); see the prior point about the function being part of a set of utility functions that ought to be callable by other Python code.
- The `cat_strings` function is fictional and for demonstration purposes; the real function is something I don't want to simply reimplement in Go.  I really am interested in how I can call a Python function from Go and get the return value.

Comment: I have a feeling that this can't be done easily using `os/exec`. All of the `os/exec` functions only return stdout and/or stderr.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/sbinet/go-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443203/writing-a-python-extension-in-go-golang

Comment: @Intermernet I thought my call to `print` in `python -c 'import pythonfile; print pythonfile.cat_strings("foo", "bar")'` would be printing to stdout.

Comment: Does it print when you just run `python -c 'import pythonfile; print pythonfile.cat_strings("foo", "bar")'` from a command prompt? If it outputs to stdout (or stderr) then it should be working from os/exec .

Comment: @Intermernet yes it does, which is why I find it strange that Go doesn't seem to be receiving the result

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to have some working code for this by simply removing the quote around the command itself:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os/exec"

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python",  "-c", "import pythonfile; print pythonfile.cat_strings('foo', 'bar')")
    fmt.Println(cmd.Args)
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil { fmt.Println(err); }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

And sure enough, in the [source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/syscall/exec_windows.go), you have this function (for Windows, at least, I don't know if that works for other OSes):

```
// EscapeArg rewrites command line argument s as prescribed
// in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms880421.
// This function returns "" (2 double quotes) if s is empty.
// Alternatively, these transformations are done:
// - every back slash (\) is doubled, but only if immediately
//   followed by double quote (");
// - every double quote (") is escaped by back slash (\);
// - finally, s is wrapped with double quotes (arg -> "arg"),
//   but only if there is space or tab inside s.
func EscapeArg(s string) string { ...
```

So your code is ending up passing the following command line call:

```
$ python -c "'import pythonfile; print pythonfile.cat_strings(\\"foo\\", \\"bar\\")'"
```

Which, if tested, evaluates to a string and returns nothing, hence the 0-length output.

Comment: Just tested on Linux (Ubuntu) and removing the single quotes works, so seems to be a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Nice ! Happy to help. Although as other suggested, if you are to make heavy use of it, you might be better off using the CPython API bindings or use a network interface to communicate between Python and Go.