# Inline python3 from golang using exec and the return result

Tags: python, bash, go

I've been following [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19403046/8913779) to call python from golang and capture the return from go code to decode a simple csv and converting into json.

This works from the cli as the command:

```
$ python3.7 -c "exec(\"import csv,json  \na=list() \nfor i in csv.DictReader(open('/Users/Astra/data_in/Data.csv', 'r')): a.append(json.dumps(i))   \nb=dict(enumerate(a))   \nc=json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True, indent=4)   \nprint(c)\")"
```

From Golang the command set as follows:

```
cmd := exec.Command("python", "-c", "import csv,json; a=list(); for i in csv.DictReader(open('/Users/Astra/data_in/Data.csv', 'r')): a.append(json.dumps(i)); b=dict(enumerate(a)); c=json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True, indent=4); print(c)")
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
exit status 1
  File "<string>", line 1
    import csv,json; a=list(); for i in csv.DictReader(open('/Users/Astra/data_in/Data.csv', 'r')): a.append(json.dumps(i)); b=dict(enumerate(a)); c=json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True, indent=4); print(c)
                                                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think I need to move back the indent parallel to the for loop but how's that possible from the stringified command?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Below is the working python equivalent, the line assigning `c` variable needs to be along the `for loop`

```
a = list()
for i in csv.DictReader(open('/Users/Astra/data_in/Data.csv', 'r')):
    a.append(json.dumps(i))
c = json.dumps(dict(enumerate(a)), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(c)
```

Comment: May I ask why you're calling an external python process instead of parsing it directly in go?

Comment: @DemianBrecht thanks for asking. It's an attempt at avoiding a huge struct definition for the csv I'm working on. I've no issue with struct as long as they are small and manageable but this 3 liner python does a great job of decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `python -`. It will read the program from `stdin`. This is useful for arbitrarily long python scripts that come from varied sources.

```
python_source = `import csv,json 
a=list()
for i in csv.DictReader(open('/Users/Astra/data_in/Data.csv', 'r')):
    a.append(json.dumps(i))
b=dict(enumerate(a))
c=json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(c)`

 cmd := exec.Command("python", "-")
 cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(python_source)
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the argument with the linefeeds and correct indentation using a raw string literal:

```
cmd := exec.Command("python", "-c", `import csv,json; 
a=list(); 
for i in csv.DictReader(open('/Users/Astra/data_in/Data.csv', 'r')): 
   a.append(json.dumps(i)); 
   b=dict(enumerate(a)); 
   c=json.dumps(b, sort_keys=True, indent=4); 
   print(c)
`)
```