# Import Golang module from Github in Python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, go, import, python-import

I have a program written in Python (.py) which requires to import and use a function written in Golang (.go) package located in Github repo.

How can I import the .go package module in python code and use the function. The function should accept args from my python code and return a value after doing some operations.

Note: I want to achieve this in Python2.7 version.

go_file.go

```
// Utility function to get string formed from input list of strings.
func NewFromStrings(inputs []string) string {
    // do something
    return "abc"
}
```

python_file.py

```
# This is just a pseudo code to make problem statement more clear.
import github.com/path_to_package/go_file

str_list = ['abc', 'def']
result = go_file.NewFromStrings(str_list)
print(result)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is just the reverse of my usecase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397986/calling-python-function-from-go-and-getting-the-function-return-value

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, but it isn't possible to directly import Go code from python without a little work.

- To do the inverse of the question you linked in your comment, you can create a small go cli to expose your Go function.  You can then execute this Go cli from python using `subprocess.run`.  The result will then be accessible from stdout. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run
- Alternatively, you can communicate using IPC, like sockets, which will involve creating a little server in Go.
- The third option I can think of is exporting your Go function in a native library and calling it from python using c bindings.  This is probably the most complicated route, but will get you closest to being able to import go code from python.

Check out this blog post with a much more thorough break down of some of your options: https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2020/06/python-go-grpc.html