# How to run/interact with a Golang executable in Python?

Tags: python, windows, go, command-line

I have a command-line Golang executable on Windows named `cnki-downloader.exe` (open-sourced here: https://github.com/amyhaber/cnki-downloader). I want to run this executable in Python, and interact with it (get its output, then input something, then get output, and so on)

It's a command-line program, so I thought it's the same as a normal Windows command-line program built by MSVC. My code is like this:

```
# coding=gbk

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["cnki-downloader.exe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
#p = Popen(["WlanHelper.exe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE )

p.stdin.write( 'XXXXXX\n' )
result1 = p.stdout.read() # <---- we never return here
print result1

p.stdin.write( '1\n' )
result2 = p.stdout.read()
print result2
```

My Python code halts at the `Popen` call with `cnki-downloader.exe` parameter. Then I tried a C command-line program built by MSVC (named `WlanHelper.exe`), it runs well. My script can get the output from the exe.

So I suspect that the command-line mechanism of the Golang executable is different from a native C/C++ program, and it's difficult for other languages (like Python) to call and interact with it.

So I want to know **how to interact with a Golang executable on Windows in other languages like Python?**. If this is impossible, I can also consider modifying the Golang program's source code (because it's open source). But I hope I won't go that step. Thanks!

---

**NOTE:**

If possible, I want to call this Golang executable directly, instead of modifying it into a library and let Python import it. If I have to modify the Golang into a library, why not just remove the interactive manner and make everything into command-line parameters? There's no need to bother writing a Golang library. So please let's assume the Golang program is closed-sourced. I don't think there's no way for Python to call a command-line Golang program. If this is the case, then I think Golang **REALLY** needs to be improved in the interoperability with other languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a Python extension in Go (Golang)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443203/writing-a-python-extension-in-go-golang)

Comment: @captncraig I think that solution requires to compile the Golang into a library instead of the current executable. Is there a way not to change the Golang executable's source code?

Comment: Ah, perhaps the fact that your target app is in go is tangential to your problem. Seems there is some problem interacting with a child process from python.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) for the subprocess module you are using, it seems they have a warning about deadlocks using `stdout.read()` and friends:

> Warning This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE
>   and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it
>   blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use
>   communicate() to avoid that.

So, maybe try using [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead?